# How to select current month from dropdownlist using C# with the help of back end code?

Tags: asp.net

Suppose i have a dropdownlist in which whole months are there in  that dropdown.I want that on page load dropdownlist select current month automatically(means with the help of back end code using C#). so how to do this ? please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your drop down contains an ordered list of months, where the first (index 0) is January, and the last (index 11) is December:

```
myDropDown.SelectedIndex = DateTime.Now.Month - 1;
```

If you have an placeholder option (eg "select value from list") as the first option, simply strip the `- 1` part to have the correct month selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
list.SelectedIndex = DateTime.Now.Month - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I'm assuming in your markup you have something like:

```
<asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id="MonthDropDownList">
    <asp:ListItem Text="January" Value="1">
    ....
    <asp:ListItem Text="December" Value="12">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then you'd want something like:

```
MonthDropDownList.Items.FindByValue(DateTime.Today.Month).Selected = true;
```